# Handle filename with blank in shellscript

Tags: shell, shell-script, sh

These are my folder structure.

```
[set symbolic links here]
/links/

[entity]    
/data/a 1/  #(folder name has blank)
/data/b 1/
/data/c 1/
/data/d 1/
.
.
.
```

I want to made symbolic link for each entities at once by shellscript.

```
for file in /data/*; do
    echo "${file}"
   ln -ds "/data/${file}" "/links/${file}"
done
```

However it shows the error like this.

```
/data/a 1
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/data//links/a 1': No such file or directory
```

I think is is relevant with blanks in folder name....???

How can I solve this??

Comment: Just put quotes around filename. **`ln -ds "/data/"${file}"" "/link/"${file}""`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's `/data//links/a 1` in the error message? I would expect `/links//data/a 1`…

Blanks are not the issue. See what your `echo` gave you. Your `$file` already contains `/data/` string. The piece of code

```
"/data/${file}" "/links/${file}"
```

adds `/data/` or `/links/` to a string where `/data/` already is.

The easiest solution is to make `$file` not contain `/data/` at all:

```
cd /data
for file in *; do
# the rest of your script
# in general remember you're in a different dir now
```

Alternatively you can keep `for file in /data/*;` and remove the excessive part later:

```
for file in /data/*; do
file=$(basename "$file")
# the rest of your script
```

The above solution will spawn multiple processes because `basename` is a separate executable. For this reason you may want the job to be done by the shell itself:

```
for file in /data/*; do
file="${file##*/}"
# the rest of your script
```

The syntax `${file##*/}` prints `$file` but removes the longest string matching `*/` from the front of it. The effect is it gives you whatever there is after the last `/`.

Comment: I use `cd` at the head of script and it works!! thank you for your precise discription. I should be more carefully.